# Is it possible to use CSS hover properties on background-images?

Tags: html, css

I have an image on a site using the `<img>` tag, but I want the image to be nested inside of a div using the 'background-image' property instead.. problem is that the image has a :hover property on it that I have to keep. Can I place hover effects on a background-image?

Edit:
Specifically what I'm looking for is to use this fancy webkit stuff activated by scrolling over the div that will affect **the image**, turning it from a b&w image to color. I have this working now with with the image sitting in an actual  tag, but I don't know how to get this to work via ':hover'

For example:

```
div.cell:hover img{
opacity:1;
filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
opacity:0.4;
}
```

this works fine and good with an image nested inside the  tag, but if I do this

```
        .A1 {background-image:url('spindrift.jpg'); background-size:cover;}
```

then obviously the hover effect isn't going to work. How can I use hover effects on a background-image?

Comment: What sort of hover effects are we talk about? Can you paste the relevant CSS?

Comment: if your background is for a div, yeah you can have `:hover` on that div. Why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have something like this currently:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img class="theImage" src="theImage.png"/>
</div>
```

And you currently have a hover on the image:

```
.theImage:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

As Jakub said in a comment, you can move the image to be a background image, and simply add a hover to the div itself:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>

.wrapper {
  background-image: url('theImage.png') no-repeat center;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible as you are placing the properties on the **element** that contains the background-image. Not the background-image on its own.

Just remove the image (`<img>`) and change the CSS so the .background element is being targeted. Then change the `:hover` to `.background:hover` so that the `.background` element is being targeted as well. The container div is just there to demonstrate its being 'nested'.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background {
    background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
    width: 100px; /* width of the image */
    height: 100px; /* height of the image */
}
.background:hover {
    /* add new properties or change current ones */
}
```